# Define the multiplication operation on the following equivalence class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble forming the proof for the following:

Let $ m > 0 $. We can define operation $\cdot$ on the equivalence classes of $ m $ as follows:
$ [a]_m \cdot [b]_m = [a \cdot b]_m $

As an example, we are given the proof for the + operation:
$ [a]_m + [b]_m = [a + b]_m $

Proof: We have to show the functions we've claimed to define are well-defined. Suppose $ a_1 \equiv a_2 $ (congruent mod $ m $) and $ b_1 \equiv b_2 $ (congruent mod $ m $). We have to show $ a_1 + b_1 \equiv a_2 + b_2 $ (congruent mod $ m $).
By assumption $ m \,|\, a_1 - a_2 $, and $ m \,|\, b_1 - b_2 $. Therefore $ m \,|\, (a_1 - a_2) + (b_1 - b_2) $, which after reorganizing the right-hand side gives $ m \,|\, (a_1 + b_1) - (a_2 + b_2) $, i.e., $ a_1 + b_1 \equiv a_2 + b_2 \, \text{mod } m $, as required.

---

I understand what "congruent mod $m$" means, but I'm unsure what an equivalence class and equivalence relation are. Based on the given example, what I thought so far was I need to find steps that will lead to $ m|(a_1 \cdot b_1)-(a_2 \cdot b_2)$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at here is the algebraic way of defining modular arithmetic.

You start with the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$.  And then, you define an equivalence relation: a way of declaring numbers 'equivalent' or 'not equivalent'.  An equivalence relation must satisfy a few properties: it has to be symmetric ($a\equiv b$ if and only if $b\equiv a$), it must be reflexive ($a\equiv a$ for all $a$), and it must be transitive ($a\equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$ implies $a\equiv c$). An equivalence relation breaks a set up into subsets of elements that are all mutually equivalent.

In this case, your equivalence relation is "differ by a multiple of $m$": $a\equiv b\pmod m$ means that $a-b=km$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This breaks $\mathbb{Z}$ up into $m$ equivalence classes: $\{0,m,2m,\ldots\}$, $\{1,m+1,2m+1,\ldots\}$, and so on up through $\{m-1,m+m-1,2m+m-1,\ldots\}$.

We usually represent this equivalence classes by something like $[a]$, where $a$ is some specific member of the class.

Now, here's where it gets interesting. You can certainly try to define $[a]\cdot[b]=[a\cdot b]$.  But, what would happen if you had chosen a different representative for the equivalence classes? After all, $[a+m]=[a]$ and $[b+2m]=[b]$.  If we had chosen $a+m$ and $b+2m$ as our representatives, our 'rule' (we haven't yet proved it is a function) would give us $[(a+m)(b+2m)]$.  To declare this a function, it has to be the case that (among other things) $[(a+m)(b+2m)]=[ab]$.

For instance, if $m=5$, is it necessarily true that the equivalence class containing $2\cdot3$ is the same as the equivalence class containing $7\cdot13$?  In order for this operation to be well-defined, you must get the same equivalence class back *no matter which representative you choose.*

So, what you are asked to show is this: if $a_1\equiv a_2\pmod{m}$ and $b_1\equiv b_2\pmod{m}$, is it necessarily true that $a_1b_1\equiv a_2b_2\pmod{m}$?

This boils down, of course, to exactly what you said you need to show: that $a_1b_1-a_2b_2$ is divisible by $m$.

As a first step, note that $a_1\equiv a_2\pmod{m}$ means there is a number $k$ so that $a_2=a_1+km$.  Similarly, there is $h$ so that $b_2=b_1+hm$.  Try plugging those into $a_1b_1-a_2b_2$, and see if you can find a way to show it is divisible by $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose , $x$ is in the class $a[m]$ and $y$ in the class $b[m]$.

Then, there are integers $u,v$ with $x=um+a$ and $y=vm+b$

Then, we have $x\cdot y=uvm^2+ubm+avm+ab\equiv ab\mod m$.

Hence, $x\cdot y$ is in the class $(ab)[m]$

This shows that the multiplication $$a[m]\cdot b[m]=(ab)[m]$$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assume as before:

\begin{align}
a_1\equiv a_2 \pmod m\\
b_1\equiv b_2 \pmod m
\end{align}

We have to show:

$$a_1b_1\equiv a_2b_2 \pmod m$$

We have:

\begin{align}
m|(a_1-a_2)\\
m|(b_1-b_2)
\end{align}

and so:

$$m|(a_1-a_2)(b_1-b_2)$$

which gives:

$$m|(a_1b_1-a_1b_2-a_2b_1+a_2b_2)\tag{1}$$

Now $-a_1b_2+a_2b_2=-b_2(a_1-a_2)$, and hence is divisible by $m$.

Similarly for $-a_2b_1+a_2b_2$.

We can therefore conclude that:

$$m|(-a_1b_2+a_2b_2-a_2b_1+a_2b_2)$$

or:

$$m|(-a_1b_2-a_2b_1+2a_2b_2)$$

Subtract this from $(1)$ to give:

$$m|(a_1b_1-a_2b_2)$$